# How do I retrieve a user's Facebook avatar in my Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, avatar

I'm trying to retrieve the currently-logged-in user's avatar image so that I can save it on my server and use it later in my application.

How would I go about getting the image directly?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

(replace USER_ID with alias or user ID...)

set source as https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture

for example large icon of a Page ID 149926629437 is:
http://graph.facebook.com/149926629437/picture?type=large

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/149926629437/picture?type=large"/>
```

more info (specify size etc...):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
part Pictures

(I also userd the aQuery (android query) to cache images...

`aq.id( holder.image).image("https://graph.facebook.com/" + USER_ID + "/picture?type=normal");`

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

It seems working fine...
)

Answer (score 0):

Can't say much about this, but you might want to try the facebook android sdk here ->https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk . Good luck :)

Comment: I m using the fb android sdk. i am getting the URL of image by using graph api but unable to save this image in Server. I have converted the image into bitmap but there is File Not found exception when i m trying to load the image in server by firing an Url.

Comment: so are you trying to use the graph api from java and get the image if i am not wrong. another alternative is to create a web script that pulls the image from the facebook account using graph api using php and use java to call your server and pull the image from facebook servers. this will help you in tracking everything easily on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Ksubedi. But I can not modify server side fetching because it will disturb some other functionality... any thing else we can do???

Answer (score 0):

If you want a higher quality profile picture try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{ID}?fields=picture.height(2048)
```

And then retrieve the `response.picture.data.url`